# Analog front end electronics

Tags: analog, filter, pulse, preamp

I am currently working on a project that involves designing some front end electronics that shape the charge pulse from a solid state detector (effectively a current source - I1 on the diagram). Our source produces a pulse that is about 10us long. The design is essentially a charge sensitive preamplifier, followed by pole zero, followed by two Sallen-Key filters in a low pass configuration that act as shaping. I have a circuit schematic [image] that works, however I should like the outcoming voltage pulse over the load (R13) to be longer. Currently, the pulse is semi-gaussian and lasts for about 200-300us. If I could double or triple this time it would work better with the readout electronics. I would also be interested to know if what i have done is correct, as I don't have a background in electronics so there may be bare faced errors in the design.

On final question on this topic is this - what is the best way to increase the height of the voltage pulse, while keeping the noise to a minimum? I can do this by changing R9 or R10, however I am wondering if there is a better way to do this. 
[image]

Comment: Can you show the waveforms of what you have and what you want?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/UvWo9 is what i have currently. I'd like to double or even triple the width of the resulting pulse

Comment: Please show how you want R13 voltage to look like.

Comment: exactly the same, but the pulse should last about 500us, not 200us

Comment: I should say, the pulsed source is around 1mA for 1us

Comment: So you want a pulse stretcher?

Comment: Is the shape of the trailing edge important?

Comment: semi gaussian is better - the overall charge deposited on the detector is proportional to the integral of the pulse so anything that integrates nicely is best. the pulse rate is 400Hz so anything that restores to baseline in this time is fine. 

Pulse stretcher sounds about right - what is that exactly

Comment: As an aside -500 mV of DC offset is quite abit for that circuit what opamps did you use? If you resolve your offset issue you can just add a gain stage at the end

Comment: I would strongly urge you to use a different topology for your shaping filter unless you have specific constraints that motivated the S&K approach. Have you tried simply using a basic CR-RC shaper? This would allow you to easily change your peaking time (by changing the time constants). By the way -- it is possible to estimate the Equivalent Noise Charge (ENC) in units of RMS Electrons in SPICE and therefore Energy Resolution in keV [FWHM]. If you are interested I can help you. I do front-end radiation detectors for a living.

Comment: @william_J That would be great - is there any way we can exchange e-mails anonymously on this site? I'm also fairly new to stack exchange... 

Thanks again for the offer.

Comment: See my profile for e-mail contact.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a peak-hold. Which feeds an analog comparator. Which triggers the ADC and the reset-delay. And use a 74122/123 delay IC, to reset the peak-hold after 1milliSecond.